# Formdata is null on backend (ajax, react, asp.net)?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api

I went through countless similar questions but I just don't get it.

It seems that the data I send is correct but the backend recieves empty formData.

```
[HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post(IFormFile formFile)
        {
          //logic throws nullreference at formFile
         }
```

Ajax:

```
 console.log($('#fileTest')[0].files[0]);
     var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('files', $('#fileTest')[0].files[0]);

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://localhost:44348/api/user/UploadFiles',
  data: fd,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data){
  alert(data);},
    error: function (jQXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log("An error occurred whilst trying to contact the server: " + jQXHR.status + " " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
                    }
```

The console.log result:

[image]

So I'm completly stuck. Can anyone suggest something I can try? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: have you tried ([FromBody] IFormFile formFile)

Comment: yes, i got 405 or 415

Comment: Try removing the IFormFile and make it the object FormFile

Comment: Also I don't know react, but in jquery you have to convert the post object into JSON